# PL/SQL function called twice from a Jasper Server Report

Tags: oracle, plsql, jasper-reports, jasperserver

I have a report that selects data from an Oracle PL/SQL function. This function executes a quite complex logic behind and returns a table to the query executor (JasperServer).

If I run this report from JasperServer just by clicking the report name it works well and returns the results as expected, the same if I run it from JasperSoft Studio.

However, if I set up a scheduler and the report is run from the scheduler on the given time, it also runs well and returns correct results, but the PL/SQL function in executed TWICE on the Oracle database. I can see it because the function produces log messages in the database (twice). The second execution starts immediatelly after the first one completes. This has never happened to me when selecting from tables or views or other functions. And this is happening ONLY when the report is scheduled or "Run in Background...".

Does anybody have any ideas why this is happening and what might be the reason for that behaviour?

Part of my report XML is below.

```
-- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
<queryString language="SQL">
<![CDATA[SELECT (TRUNC(SYSDATE) - to_number(TO_CHAR(sysdate, 'd')) - 6) week_start,
  (TRUNC(SYSDATE)      - to_number(TO_CHAR(sysdate, 'd')) + 1 - 1/24/3600) week_end,
  b15.subrepid,
  b15.subrepname,
  b15.numof,
  b15.volume,
  b15.revenue
    FROM TABLE(bs01.TEST_XBTOP_P_reports.bsr015()) b15]]>
</queryString>
    <field name="WEEK_START" class="java.sql.Timestamp"/>
    <field name="WEEK_END" class="java.sql.Timestamp"/>
    <field name="SUBREPID" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="SUBREPNAME" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="NUMOF" class="java.math.BigDecimal"/>
    <field name="VOLUME" class="java.math.BigDecimal"/>
    <field name="REVENUE" class="java.math.BigDecimal"/>
    <sortField name="SUBREPID"/>
-- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
```

My PL/SQL function is:

```
-- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE body TEST_XBTOP_P_reports
AS
  -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
  FUNCTION bsr015
    RETURN xbtop_y_bsr015_tab
  AS
    r_tab xbtop_y_bsr015_tab := xbtop_y_bsr015_tab();
    subrepid              CHAR(2);
    subrepname            CHAR(35);
    numof                 NUMBER;
    volume                NUMBER;
    revenue               NUMBER ;
    systimestamp_hostname VARCHAR2(200 CHAR);
  BEGIN
-- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
```

I run JasperReports Server Community 6.3 and Oracle SE 11.2.0.3.0.

Any ideas would be more then appreciated.

Thank you and kind regards

Pawel

Comment: Looks like the scheduler tweaks the report twice. Do you have some log of scheduler running?

Comment: I cannot see the scheduler logs - do you know where they are? I have just noticed that my reports generate two files, HTML and Excel and then they run the SQL query twice. If I generate only one output format, the SQL is run only once. However, when I specify 4 output formats (e.g. Html, Excel, PDF, CSV) the SQL is still run only twice and not four times. Is this expected?

Comment: `If I generate only one output format, the SQL is run only once. However, when I specify 4 output formats (e.g. Html, Excel, PDF, CSV) the SQL is still run only twice and not four times. Is this expected?` - Looks like some kind of optimization at server side. `I have just noticed that my reports generate two files, HTML and Excel and then they run the SQL query twice.` - Looks strange if compare with 4 exporters case.

Comment: Try to enable additional logging (log4j.properties). Another way is to look at source code

Comment: What version of JRS are you using?

Comment: I run JasperReports Server Community 6.3.0 and Oracle SE 11.2.0.3.0.

Comment: Thank you Alex K - what would I need to set up in log4j.properties to see more useful messages?.
At this moment I can only see that my SQLs are run twice and they correspond to my internal logging. But cannot see any reasons for that.
Log messages from my PL/SQL function:

`17-JUN-17 00.33.04 TEST_XBTOP_P_REPORTS.bsr015() END`
`16-JUN-17 23.35.14 TEST_XBTOP_P_REPORTS.bsr015() START`
`16-JUN-17 23.35.14 TEST_XBTOP_P_REPORTS.bsr015() END`
`16-JUN-17 22.38.26 TEST_XBTOP_P_REPORTS.bsr015() START`

Comment: In /opt/jasperreports-server-cp-6.3.0/apache-tomcat/webapps/jasperserver/WEB-INF/logs/jasperserver.log.1

2017-06-16 22:38:26,225 DEBUG JRJdbcQueryExecuter,quartzScheduler_Worker-3:362 - SQL query string: SELECT (TRUNC(SYSDATE) - to_number(TO_CHAR(sysdate, 'd')) - 6) week_start,
  (TRUNC(SYSDATE)      - to_number(TO_CHAR(sysdate, 'd')) + 1 - 1/24/3600) week_end,
  b15.subrepid,
  b15.subrepname,
  b15.numof,
  b15.volume,
  b15.revenue
FROM TABLE(bs01.TEST_XBTOP_P_reports.bsr015()) b15

Comment: [...]
2017-06-16 23:35:14,872 DEBUG JRJdbcQueryExecuter,quartzScheduler_Worker-3:362 - SQL query string: SELECT (TRUNC(SYSDATE) - to_number(TO_CHAR(sysdate, 'd')) - 6) week_start,
  (TRUNC(SYSDATE)      - to_number(TO_CHAR(sysdate, 'd')) + 1 - 1/24/3600) week_end,
  b15.subrepid,
  b15.subrepname,
  b15.numof,
  b15.volume,
  b15.revenue
FROM TABLE(bs01.TEST_XBTOP_P_reports.bsr015()) b15